# How the Unity container will resolve the registered type

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

Recently I am going through some  old code and found the below code

```
public class ProfileModule : IModule
{
    private readonly IRegionManager regionManager;
    private readonly IUnityContainer container;
    private IEventAggregator eventAggregator;

    public ProfileModule(IUnityContainer c, IRegionManager r, IEventAggregator e)
    {
        container = c;
        regionManager = r;
        eventAggregator = e;
     }

    public void Initialize()
    {    
       // Create and add profiles as new Tab items
       container.RegisterType<IProfileViewModel, Profile1ViewModel>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
       regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.HomeRegion].Add(container.Resolve<ProfileView>());// HomeRegion is of type TabControl

       container.RegisterType<IProfileViewModel, Profile2ViewModel>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
       regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.HomeRegion].Add(container.Resolve<ProfileView>());

       container.RegisterType<IProfileViewModel, Profile3ViewModel>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
       regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.HomeRegion].Add(container.Resolve<ProfileView>());
     }
}
```

Below is the ProfileView.xaml.cs

```
public partial class ProfileView : INotifyPropertyChanged
{   
    [InjectionConstructor]
    public ProfileView(IProfileViewModel vm)
    {
        DataContext = vm;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Below are the viewModels

```
public abstract class ProfileViewModelBase : IProfileViewModel, IDataErrorInfo, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ProfileViewModelBase(IEventAggregator eventAggregator, IRegionManager regionManager)
    {

    }
}


public class Profile1ViewModel : ProfileViewModelBase
{  
    [InjectionConstructor]
    public Profile1ViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator, IRegionManager regionManager)
        : base (eventAggregator, regionManager)
    {

    }
}

public class Profile2ViewModel : ProfileViewModelBase
{  
    [InjectionConstructor]
    public Profile2ViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator, IRegionManager regionManager)
        : base (eventAggregator, regionManager)
    {

    }
}


public class Profile3ViewModel : ProfileViewModelBase
{  
    [InjectionConstructor]
    public Profile3ViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator, IRegionManager regionManager)
        : base (eventAggregator, regionManager)
    {

    }
}
```

The part of the code that is not clear for me is the ProfileModule.Initialise().
Everytime when the region manager is adding a view a new new instance of ProfileView is getting created and the viewModel is the one that is registered last.

First time ProfileView is created with Profile1ViewModel as a Datacontext.
Second time ProfileView is created with Profile2ViewModel as a Datacontext.
Third time ProfileView is created with Profile3ViewModel as a Datacontext.

1. How the container knows exactly which viewmodel to create when creating the view.
2. Also I understand , container.Resolve will return the view if it already got one, first time view is created and returned, second time I except same view will be returned, but a new view is created. same with third.

Can anyone explain what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here goes:

1. What you can see inside the `Initialize` method is that after registering the `IProfileViewModel` the code is then immediately calling `Resolve<ProfileView>` which on the first `Resolve` is providing `Profile1ViewModel` to the `ProfileView` constructor. Then the second `Register` **replaces** the first registration with Profile2ViewModel. Therefore subsequent calls to `Resolve` will never give you an instance (or the singleton instance) of `Profile1ViewModel`.
2. If for some reason you really want to resolve the same instance of `ProfileView` then you need to `Register` this with the Unity container as a singleton like the below.

   container.RegisterType(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

This is obviously assuming you have an `interface` defined called `IProfileView`

Comment: For some very strange reason the code formatting is not displaying

Comment: Thank you Bijington. This answers me.

Comment: I never though a replace will happen if we register again.                         In `Initilaise()` the code is nothing but   `regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.HomeRegion].Add(new profileView(new profile1ViewModel()); regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.HomeRegion].Add(new profileView(new profile2ViewModel()); regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.HomeRegion].Add(new profileView(new profile3ViewModel()); ` as the `container` will not have any reference to the view and lost the reference to viewModels.

Comment: If you wanted to register multiple implementations against the same interface then you need to pass in a string in the RegisterType method but be aware you will need to use it when calling Resolve as well, or use ResolveAll

Comment: The code is essentially that although any further calls will resolve Profile3ViewModel